# What REGEX pattern should I use to look for a specific string pattern and remove anything else that doesnt match?

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

I'm parsing through code **using a Perl-REGEX parsing engine in my IDE** and I want to grab any variables that look like

```
$hash->{ hash_key04}
```

and nuke the rest of the code..

So far my very basic REGEX doesnt do what I expected

```
(.*)(\$hash\-\>\{[\w\s]+\})(.*)


(
\$
hash
\-\>
\{
  [\w\s]+
\}
)
```

I know to use replace for this ($1,$2,etc), but match (.*) before and after the target string doesnt seem to capture all the rest of the code!

**UPADTED:**
tried matching null but of course thats too greedy.

```
([^\0]*)
```

What expression in regex should i use to look only for the string pattern and remove the rest?

The problem is I want to be left with the list of $hash->{} strings after the replace runs in the IDE.

Comment: Consider adding either /s or /m for single/multi-line matching, also, did you mean 0-9 instead of 0-p?

Comment: thanks @mrk, the problem is my regex expression is wrong. Not sure how to make it what I need. Because there are other $vars and { and } and -> in there that should not be captured, only the $hash->{(.*)} should be matched.

Comment: If the braces can contain nested braces, then you are venturing into irregular expression territory, and you'll need something more like [`Text::Balanced`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::Balanced)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is better approached from the other direction.  Instead of trying to delete everything you don't want, what about extracting everything you do want?

```
my @vars = $src_text =~ /(\$hash->\{[\w\s]+\})/g;
```

Breaking down the regex:

```
    /(                  # start of capture group
       \$hash->         # prefix string with $ escaped
       \{               # opening escaped delimiter
        [\w\s]+         # any word characters or space
       \}               # closing escaped delimiter
    )/g;                # match repeatedly returning a list of captures
```

---

Here is another way that might fit within your IDE better:

```
s/(\$hash->\{[\w\s]+\})|./$1/gs;
```

This regex tries to match one of your hash variables at each location, and if it fails, it deletes the next character and then tries again, which after running over the whole file will have deleted everything you don't want.

Comment: Good one! except one problem. While I'm using perl regex I'm not using perl code, this is a replace function inside an IDE. Sorry I didnt clarify that, I updated my question to reflect that point.

Comment: Ahh, the fun of restricted regex engines...  On the other hand, most IDEs support setting up macros that will grab a selection or the whole file, pass it through an external program (perl in this case) and then feed the result back into the file.  Could you setup something like that?

Comment: OMG that worked!!! You rock my socks! Very slow and clunky but it did that and left me a bunch of newlines in between the vars!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the platform, but generally, replace the pattern with an empty string.

In javascript,

```
// prints "the la in ing"
console.log('the latest in testing'.replace(/test/g, ''));
```

In bash

```
$ echo 'the latest in testing' | sed 's/test//g'
the la in ing
```

In C#

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("the latest in testing", "test", ""));
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your coding language. What you want is group 2 (The second set of characters in parenthesis). In perl that would be $2, in VIM it would be \2, etc ...

Comment: sorry about that, I updated the question with full info. Using Perl, need help with the expression.

Comment: After calling the regex the varible $2 should have what you want.

Answer (score 0):

By default the wildcard `.` won't match newlines. You can enable newlines in its matching set using a flag depending on what regex standard you're using and under what language/api. Or you can add them explicitly yourself by defining a character set:

```
[.\n\r]*    <- Matches any character including newline, carriage return.
```

Combine this with capture groups to grab desired variables from your code and skip over lines which contain no capture group.

If you want help constructing the proper regex for your context you'll need to paste some input text and specify what the output should be.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add a ^ to the beginning of the regex s/^.*(PATTERN)(.*)$/$1/ so that it starts at the beginning of the line and goes to the end, removing anything except that pattern.